# Extracting info. from XML into Cocoa

Tags: xml, cocoa, nsxml

I am trying to parse an XML to extract values of certain variables. Here's an example:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
  <Main xmlns='http://www.abc.uk' version='1.0' name='full'>
    <child1 version='2.0'>
    <value1> xyz </value1>
    <userinfo>
       <name> joe </name>
       <pass> joepass </pass>
   </userinfo>
    </child1>
</Root>
```

Question:
How do I extract the 'xyz' value to display ?
How do I extract 'joe' and 'joepass' to display ?

From my understanding, child1 is the root with attribute 'version'. 'value1' and 'userinfo' are both elements. In Cocoa, how would I display these values ? I can do a [child elementsForName:@"userinfo" and it displays all the values. I need to specifically extract 'joe' and 'joepass'. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically? On what language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I extract the 'xyz' value to
>   display ? How do I extract 'joe' and
>   'joepass' to display ?

With something like this. This assumes you have your XML in an `NSString`:

```
NSXMLDocument* xmlDoc;
NSError* error = nil;
NSUInteger options = NSXMLNodePreserveWhitespace|NSXMLDocumentTidyXML;
xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:xmlString
                                          options:options
                                            error:&error];
if (!error)
{
    NSArray* value1Nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@".//Main/value1" error:&error];
    if (!error)
    {
        NSXMLNode* value1node = [value1Nodes objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* value1 = [value1node stringValue];
        // .. do something with value1
    }

    NSArray* userInfoNodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@".//Main/userinfo" error:&error];
    if (!error)
    {
        for (NSXMLNode* userInfoNode in userInfoNodes)
        {
            NSXMLNode* nameNode = [[userInfoNode nodesForXPath:@"./name" error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];
            NSXMLNode* passNode = [[userInfoNode nodesForXPath:@"./pass" error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString* name = [nameNode stringValue];
            NSString* pass = [passNode stringValue];
            // .. do something with name and pass
    }
}
```

See more details in Apple's [Tree-Based XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/QueryingXML.html).

> From my understanding, child1 is the
>   root with attribute 'version'.
>   'value1' and 'userinfo' are both
>   elements.

`Main` is the root node in this XML document, not `child1`.