# How To use Xml file as a data source in xcode 4.6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.6

I'm new to xcode. I need to know how can we use an **xml file as data source in xcode 4.6** for example I've a xml file like this

```
<Catalog>
    <Title>title1</Title>
    <Description>desc2</Description>
</Catalog>
```

and **I've 2 labels** and I need to set **their text as title1 and desc2** using the xml file How can I achieve that in xcode 4.6. Please help

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Among many other duplicates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072979/how-do-i-read-and-write-xml-in-cocoa-touch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237757/cocoa-objective-c-best-practice-to-parse-xml-document http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739854/extracting-info-from-xml-into-cocoa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274513/cocoa-obj-c-simple-xml-file-reader-need-help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010810/read-modify-write-xml-file-in-cocoa

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSXMLParser` to convert the xml data into `NSDictionary`  and use that dictionary data for showing in required labels.